# How to quickly compute missing cumulative sums in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The question is a bit hard to describe in words, so I'll just use an example here to illustrate.

Suppose I have a dataframe like this:

```
idx start_time end_time dt 
1   0          1        1
1   1          3        2
1   3          x        3
2   0          2        2
2   2          6        4
2   6          x        5
```

This table consists of a column called `idx` where unique `idx` is adjacently located as shown in the table. Each unique `idx` should have the same number of rows (I'm not certain of this, but I think this is the case, but perhaps for the sake of this question, let's not rely on this).

Suppose I am given this table. I need to compute `x`, which is the value of `end_time` for the last row of each unique `idx`. `end_time` is simply a cumulative sum of `dt`. Since I am given a table like this, what is the quickest way I can compute `x`?

I'm hoping for a solution that's quicker than looping through every row, but it seems there may not be such a solution unless we know the number of rows each unique `idx` has.

I'm looking for something like

```
df["end_time"].iloc[-1] = df["end_time"].iloc[-2] + df["dt"].iloc[-1]
```

but this only works if the dataframe has 1 unique index.

Edit: technically the input is such that `end_time` column is empty, but I can quickly compute all the end_times for each unique idx, excluding the last row, with

```
df["end_time"] = df["start_time"].shift(periods=-1).fillna(0).astype(float)
```

which then produces the table in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = {'idx': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
        'start_time': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 6},
        'end_time': {0: '1', 1: '3', 2: 'x', 3: '2', 4: '6', 5: 'x'},
        'dt': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 4, 5: 5}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('idx')
```

`df`

```
    start_time  end_time    dt
idx         
1   0           1           1
1   1           3           2
1   3           x           3
2   0           2           2
2   2           6           4
2   6           x           5
```

**Code**

```
df.assign(end_time=df.groupby(level=0)['dt'].cumsum())
```

result:

```
    start_time  end_time    dt
idx         
1   0           1           1
1   1           3           2
1   3           6           3
2   0           2           2
2   2           6           4
2   6           11          5
```